# Notebook won't shut down after upgrading to w10

Tags: laptop, windows-10, shutdown

My notebook will keep the fan and the power button light on even after shuting it down from windows, any real fix to this? No matter how much time I give it, it will always stay on and drain the battery, the only way to shut it down is by holding the power button for a few secs but that will probably damage the computer soon.

I tried a lot of things and nothing worked, I tried:

- Holding control while pressing shut down.
- Downgrading intel drivers.
- Uninstalling everything intel related.
- Re-installing w10.
- Getting all the updates.
- Disabled fast boot options.
- Changed energy settings.
- Changing what the power button do.
- Restarting default bios settings.

Nothing worked so far, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the BIOS in UEFI/BIOS and does it have Secure Boot enabled? Also is this an HP device? There seem to be a lot of posts specifically about HP devices.
If so [this reddit thread](https://m.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3hagj0/working_longterm_solution_to_the_sleep/) might have the answer.

I will update this answer once more information is added as I can't currently comment.

Comment: the computer is a msi cx61 i3 with 4gbs of ram, the bios it is on uefi mode and has intel speedstep enabled

Answer (score 0):

In your control panel, go to the power applet, choose what the power buttons do, change settings that are currently unavailable, and uncheck fast startup.

Comment: As I said, I already did that and it didn't work